# coldfusion problem with flash form binding : PART 2

Tags: coldfusion, cfform

I am not sure why this one gives me "undefined". the imgNames are there.

```
  <cfquery name="getArt" datasource="cfartgallery">
   select * from art where artid < 10
 </cfquery>
 <cfdump var="#getArt#">
 <cfform name="myform" width="620" height="750" format="Flash" timeout="100" preservedata="yes" wmode="transparent">    
<cfformitem type="script">
    function updateSelectedArt():Void{
      var elem;
      var imgName;
      var values = [];
      var total  = parseInt(myform.pickmany_total);
      for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
        elem = _root["pickmany"+ i];
        imgName = _root["img"+ i];
          if (elem.selected) {
              values.push(imgName.value);
          }
      }    
      // use whatever delmiter makes sense
      _root["pickmany_selected"].text = values.join(",");
   }    
</cfformitem>
<cfoutput query="getArt">
    <cfinput name="pickmany#currentRow#" type="checkbox" value="#artname#" onClick="updateSelectedArt()" label="#artname#"><br/>
    <cfinput name="img#currentRow#" type="text" value="#largeImage#"><br/>
</cfoutput>
<cfinput type="hidden" name="pickmany_total" value="#getArt.recordCount#">
   <cfinput type="text" name="pickmany_selected"  value="" size="50">
  </cfform>
```

Comment: Glad you got it working but I'd advise using AJAX features instead of flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oopsie..

it is supposed to be   values.push(imgName.text);

this works:

```
   <cfquery name="getArt" datasource="cfartgallery">
     select * from art where artid < 10
  </cfquery>
  <cfdump var="#getArt#">
  <cfform name="myform" width="620" height="750" format="Flash" timeout="100" preservedata="yes" wmode="transparent">    
<cfformitem type="script">
    function updateSelectedArt():Void{
      var elem;
      var imgName;
      var values = [];
      var total  = parseInt(myform.pickmany_total);
      for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
        elem = _root["pickmany"+ i];
        imgName = _root["img"+ i];
          if (elem.selected) {
              values.push(imgName.text);
          }
      }    
      // use whatever delmiter makes sense
      _root["pickmany_selected"].text = values.join(",");
   }    
</cfformitem>
<cfoutput query="getArt">
    <cfinput name="pickmany#currentRow#" type="checkbox" value="#artname#" onClick="updateSelectedArt()" label="#artname#"><br/>
    <cfinput name="img#currentRow#" type="text" value="#largeImage#"><br/>
</cfoutput>
<cfinput type="hidden" name="pickmany_total" value="#getArt.recordCount#">
<cfinput type="text" name="pickmany_selected"  value="" size="50">
 </cfform>
```

Comment: Ah, the weirdness of flash forms ;) Where checkboxes are `selected`. A `value` is `text`, and hidden fields have no `text` or `value`.

Comment: Leigh. Yes, hidden field has no value. I wanted to make an array out of getArt query with the image names and use something like values.push(imgArr[i]);     that didn't work

Comment: Btw, I do not always check comments on closed threads. But if you put an @ symbol in front of my name it will show in my inbox.

Comment: @Leigh, thanks for the great tip! still learning how to use this site.

Answer (score 0):

this is without the text field:

```
  function updateSelectedArt():Void{
       var elem;
       var imgName;
       var values = [];
       var imgArray = [];
       <cfoutput query="getArt">
        imgArray[#getArt.currentRow#] = '#getArt.largeImage#';
       </cfoutput>
       var total  = <cfoutput>#getArt.recordCount#</cfoutput>;
       for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
           elem = _root["pickmany"+ i];
           imgName = _root["img"+ i];
           if (elem.selected) {
                values.push(imgArray[i]);
            }
       }    
       _root["pickmany_selected"].text = values.join(",");
     }
```

Comment: You could probably use toScript() to convert cf objects to actionscript objects automatically. I am not sure if arrays versus text fields would make any difference in terms of compilation.